# Redirect nginx errors to php

Tags: php, nginx

My aim is to have any error in nginx (i.e. 404, 405 etc...) be redirected to my php script located at `index.php`.
`

```
server {

    root /usr/share/nginx/TradeLog/www/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    error_page 403 404 /index.php/;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* \.php$
    {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600; # Set fairly high for debugging
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        expires max;
    }
}
```

`

However, when I attempt this, I am greeted with an nginx 404 error. What am I doing wrong here?

### EDIT

I have found that if I turn `fastcgi_intercept_errors on` to `off`, then nginx deals with the errors. My next step is to then set a new request for the php script which will display errors. This is at the location `/errors/code/<code_number>`.

Say I had the following location block:

`location = /composer.phar
    {
        return 403;
    }`

I want to then redirect to the error page at `/error/code/403`

Therefore, I was thinking

`error_page 403 = /error/code/403;`

would do the trick for me, but my php script is still picking up the original request - I always show a 404 page because my PHP script is getting a request for a location that it doesn't know. I want nginx to tell it which page to display externally and then just pass the scrip the error number.

Comment: Try something like - `error_page 403 404 /40x.html; location = /40x.html { index index.php; }`

Comment: this gives me a 404 still. I'm not too sure how this is supposed to work anyway. Why would i navigate to the index if I have already specified the location?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should replace:

```
error_page 403 404 /index.php/;
```

with:

```
error_page 403 404 /index.php;
```

The extra / make the redirection to a directory, not to a file. The rest of your configuration seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is working 
error_page   404  =  /index.php;